# Getting data on Java with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, tostring

I'm kind of new in java and I need some help.
I'm creating an Mp3 Player in Java for an college activity. Well, first I need to get all the Artist information. So I created the Artist class:

```
public class Artist {

    int id;
    String Artist_name, country;


            //This is the contructor
    Artist(int id, String Artist_name, String country){
    this.id = id;
    this.Artist_name = Artist_name;
    this.country = country;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }




    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




    public String getArtist_name() {
        return Artist_name;
    }




    public void setArtist_name(String Artist_name) {
        Artist_name = Artist_name;
    }




    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }



    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }



    //This is the toString method. I must use it for this activity. It just links everything.
    public String toString(){   
        return "ID: " + id + "\n" + "Name: " + artist_name + "\n" + "Country: " + country;
    }
```

Ok, now I just need an ArtistTest class to test everything. The first 2 instances, it has to be a hardcode insert, and then, the third one is a regular user-insert, using BufferedReader. And that's my problem, how can I do this? And then, how can I use the toString method to print all the three Artists?
This is the (incomplete and possibly wrong) code I've made so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ArtistTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Artist band1, band2;

            //Just hardcode.
    try{
    band1 = new Artist(1,"The Beatles","England");
    band2 = new Artist(2,"The Rolling Stones","England");
    }

    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error");
    }

    //The problem...
    BufferedReader band3= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try{
        System.out.print("ID:");
                    ...
        System.out.print("Artist Name:");
                   ...
        System.out.print("Country:");
                   ...
}

    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Erro");
    }

    toString(...)
}

}
```

Thanks in advice!

Comment: first of all why not use Scanner() instead of BufferedReader ?

Comment: Did you read the Java tutorial on input and output? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ or read the Java docs for `BufferedReader` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: Why use `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader` if the ID, artist name, and country are just going to be entered on separate lines?

Comment: Why does the Artist class have setters? Why not just make Artist immutable?

Comment: The Artist class have setters and getters just beacause it was part of the teacher's requirement. The same reason why I should use BufferedReader instead of Scanner(). Yes, my teacher makes everything more difficult.

Comment: Presumably you have a file with a list of artists. How to read this file depends on the format. Can you provide some sample data from the file? Just a few lines to get the idea

Comment: Well, actually the user is going to insert the information. It will insert an ID, the name of the band, and the country. Then, the toString() method will put everything togheter. Then, it will be printed on screen.